# Key Delay In Logic Editor

Tags: logic-bricks

I want to make it so when the player presses **spacebar** they cant press it again in another 1,5 seconds, im not sure how to use the state or delay sensor/actuator someone please help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Information**

Use an game-property with type `integer`.

**Blend File** (made in a UPBGE 0.2x release)

https://blend-exchange.com/b/AEQKXKbY

**Screenshot**

[image]